# ModuleNotFoundError for multi-level package directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My project is structured like this:

`project/
--bin/
----__init__.py
----server/
------__init__.py
------server.py
----tool/
------__init__.py
------tool.py`

In `bin/server/server.py`, I have this import:

`from bin.tool.tool import tool_class`

And when I run `python3 bin/server/server.py`, I get this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bin'`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in another IDE, and I solved it by making the folder I am importing from as a source folder.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I had this problem in PyCharm, what I did is I went to the project settings, and I made my project folder a source folder. This means I added it to my source list. I am not sure how would you do this in in your IDE. It is just a hint for you